# Why can't I use alias to filter when doing fetch join?

Tags: jpa

I have a sudden question
Why can't I use alias to filter when doing fetch join?

As an answer to this, it seems that you usually say that the consistency between the db state and the object state is broken.
If you filter using an alias, you will get fewer data than the actual data in the db.
However, if you need to return only the filtered result as a result anyway
I think it would be ok to use
Why does it matter if the db state and object state are inconsistent?
So I thought about it, but it seems to be the next big thing

- May be difficult to maintain
- Caching problem

But I don't know if those two problems are really big problems...;
Maintenance may be difficult, but I'm not sure how difficult it will be, and I'm not sure how much the caching problem will be affected by that code...

Comment: Will you show any [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

JPA didn't allow it,  I believe because the entities returned are managed. JPA providers are on the hook to calculate any changes to the entity. Without the entity read in matching the actual state in the database (ie if you were able to filter relationships), it would be much more difficult to determine what has changed - if you try to add something you've filtered out, should JPA providers silently ignore it or throw an exception because it already exists in the DB representation? Providers can and do allow filtering on mappings, but they are usually more 'static' so repeatable